# Grabbing an element from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Okay. I know this is duplicate.

However, I am a decent programmer, I have been trying this for 2 hours and got nothing!!

The top several lines of the xml file looks like the following.

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">2</int>
    <lst name="params">
        <str name="d">100</str>
        <str name="sort">score asc</str>
        <str name="fl">
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

Here, what I want to get is just the number between `<int name="QTime">` and `</int>`, which is 2 in this case.

How can I do this?
I've used `ElementTree`, and the documentation is awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lxml.etree`, and assuming `<response>` is the document root, you can do this:

```
import lxml.etree
xml = lxml.etree.parse(<file-like object>)
root = xml.getroot()
elements = root.xpath("int[@name='QTime']")
values = [int(x.text.strip()) for x in elements]
```

where `<file-like object>` can be an opened `file` object or a `StringIO::StringIO` object, etc...

`elements` will be a list of `<int name="QTime">` elements. `values` will be the corresponding list of integer values.

If `<response>` is not the document root, you can use `//response/int[@name='QTime']` in `xpath` instead.

Comment: `//int` scans all elements, is slower, and can return more results than intended. Assuming <response> is the top level element in the tree, `'int[@name="QTime"]'`